# How export table data using procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

We need to export some table’s data into file. We are selecting the table names programmatically.
So we are trying to do this using a procedure, we have created a sample procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE export_dynamic() 
BEGIN 
set @myvar = 'SELECT * INTO OUTFILE ''E:\\MYSQL-DUMP\\tabletest.txt'' FROM tabletest'; 
PREPARE STMT FROM @myvar;
EXECUTE STMT;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;
END; 
$$
```

But when we CALL this procedure we are getting following Error

```
CALL export_dynamic()   Error Code: 1. Can't create/write to file 'E:MYSQL-DUMP abletest.txt' (Errcode: 22 - Invalid argument)  0.000
```

When we run the following query In MySQL workbench works fine

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'E:\\MYSQL-DUMP\\tabletest.txt' FROM tabletest
```

Is there any way to export a table using mysql procedure?

Comment: What do you think @myvar looks like after it is set?

Comment: **@myvar** will have value
`SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'E:\\MYSQL-DUMP\\tabletest.txt' FROM tabletest`

Comment: Try a `SELECT @myvar` after calling the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the err msg. The interface you're using is eating your backslashes.

Try using forward slashes, mysql often will translate them into the required.